# Opera desktop browser development

Tags: javascript, python, c, .net

I am curious and need to know which platform or IDE to make a desktop application like opera browser `https://www.opera.com`

Answer (score 0):

there are many IDE which provide webviewer class.
For example, QT is a kind of powerful library.
If you start qtSDK, you can check webbrowser on the example tag.

Or you may use ElectronJS(javascript library for cross-platform app development).
https://electronjs.org

Comment: Thank you for the answer i just need to know operas coding insfrasturcture

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries and frameworks of JavaScript and you may either use Express JS, React Js , Flutter for the development of browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33620158)